# how to add cue points to mp4 in flash cc

Tags: actionscript-3, video, video-streaming

I am just starting a video project and have a need to react accurately at specified points in an mp4 video.

There used to be the functionality to add cue points to flv videos but I don't think this is available for flashh cc and mp4.

What other technique would anyone recommend to accurately react to a certain point in the video.

Thanks

Comment: There's a [post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1970046) on Adobe Forums discussing this.

Comment: You can write you own code to add/fire cue-points according to your stream playing manner (FLVPlayback component (see the answer of @user3290142), a NetStream object, ... ) ...

Comment: What type of reaction? Could multiple `If` statements in some `enterFrame` function work. Something like `if ( myNS.time == 5.0 ) { do something if video time is 5 secs }` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can still add cue points when using mp4 with the following method:

```
var cueTime:Number = 20;
var cueName:String = "Chapter1"
var player:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
player.source = "myMovie.mp4";
player.addASCuePoint(cueTime, cueName);
player.addEventListener(MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT, CuePointHandler);

function CuePointHandler(eventObject:MetadataEvent):void{
    if (eventObject.info.name == cueName) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using flasg cc2014 for this and don't seem to have the flvplayback functionality. Is there a way to add cuepoints to a video played using netstream?

Comment: What classes are you using? Can you post a sample of the code you use to play the mp4?

Comment: It looks like @userakmozo probably gave the best answer. You might need to write a class that gives you the functionality of "addASCuePoint". Basically it would check the time of the video on a timer and then dispatch a new event if the cuepoint matched.